# How to Build different APK files using different databases in Android using Gradle tool?

Tags: android, gradle

We have a platform to read poetry with a SQLITE Database say SHAKESPEARE.DB .
We also have another poetry say Wordsworth.DB.
So for each poetry database we want to create a separate application like Shakespeare.apk and wordsworth.apk.

During build we want to mention the Database and mention the name of the APK.

How do we Change Database during android build through gradle and deploy different APK's
I would want to Create and Deploy Database specific APK using Gradle ?

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Use a consistent means of embedding the database in the app. For this answer, I will assume that you are [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), with the database packaged as `words.db` in `assets/`.

Step #2: Create two product flavors for your app in your `app/` module's `build.gradle` file. For this answer, I will call these flavors `vanilla` and `chocolate`:

```
productFlavors {
    vanilla {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.android.gradle.hello.vanilla"
    }

    chocolate {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.android.gradle.hello.chocolate"
    }
}
```

(replace the `applicationId` values with ones more relevant to your project)

Step #3: Create a sourceset for each flavor (`app/src/vanilla`, `app/src/chocolate/`).

Step #4: Put a different `words.db` in `assets/` of the flavor (`app/src/vanilla/assets/words.db`, `app/src/chocolate/assets/words.db`).

Now, when you build `vanilla`, it will use the `vanilla` edition of `words.db`. When you build `chocolate`, it will use the `chocolate` edition of `words.db`. No Java code changes are required. You can also put different resources in those flavor-specific sourcesets, for different icons, labels, etc. Because you have different `applicationId` values, both flavors can be installed on your test devices at the same time, and both flavors can be distributed through app distribution channels like the Play store.